# How to remove border of a trace in plotlyjs box plot without removing line representing median?

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly, boxplot, plotly.js

[Box plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdBaZ.png)

I am trying to remove border from the trace

I used this code to remove border line but it removes the line as well which represents median and I don't want that-

```
    var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 8, 9, 10],
  type: 'box',
  name: 'Set 1',
  line: {
    width: 0
  }
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7],
  type: 'box',
  name: 'Set 2',
  line: {
    width: 0
  }
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
  title: 'Horizontal Box Plot'
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

[Box plot after I set line-width to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGlkg.png)

In addition I also want to know how to thicken line for median, I have tried eveything mentioned in their documentation but nothing is working as I expected.